# How to change the InfoPlist.strings's name

Tags: ios, xcode

Now I have already have a localizable.strings. But when I want to change the app display name to localizable. The Application has localized display name can't find the string from localizable.string. Just when I change the name to InfoPlist.strings,It can works.But the text in application doesn't work. How to resgister the localizalbe.strings's name to the localized display name.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a useful guide on how to localize your Info.plist file, thus your application name (bundle display name) [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/15/localize-iphone-application-name.html).

EDIT after comment:

The `InfoPlist.strings` is the localisation file for your `Info.plist` file. You should not change its name.
It is used to localise **only** the strings inside your `Info.plist` file.

To localize other strings in your application, you will need another seperate `Localizable.strings` bundle.

So in your project you would have:

- `InfoPlist.strings`

**and**

- `Localizable.strings`

There are a number of other useful resources you can read here in relation to internationalization:

http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

Comment: See the doc. My question is how to change the name for InfoPlist.strings. Because only I change name to InfoPlist.strings.The display name localized works. Now I create a files such as bbb.strings. How to resgister to bundle so App can make display name localizable works.